snowflake native app read access to a table
Hi i'm trying to make my snowflake native app work, i followed the tutorial
https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/getting_started_with_native_apps/#0
and i am unable to transform it so it does what i want it to do, right now i would like to simply be able to select a table in the account the app is being installed ( dev.dev.t table )
however i am unable to do that - on my frontend when i click the shield button and grant the access to this table i still cannot use it in any way, i wrote in the app a simple procedure to check if i can select given table and it fails
my procedure

create or replace procedure app_instance_schema.p_select(t varchar )
returns varchar  
language sql 
as $$
declare 
    query varchar default 'select * from ' || t;
begin 
    execute  immediate :query ; 
    return 'ok';
end;
$$;

does anyone know how to achieve this ?
[edit1]
when i issue
SHOW REFERENCES IN APPLICATION DATA_FIT_APP_MYAPP;
i do see a row with a referency to a table of mine

[edit2]
ok i made it work - thank you stackoverflow!
The trick is to use reference syntax, aka the procedure should look like that
create or replace procedure app_instance_schema.p_select(t varchar )
returns varchar  
language sql 
as $$
declare 
    query varchar default 'select * from reference(''' || t || ''')';
begin 
    execute  immediate :query ; 
    return 'ok';
end;
$$;

this transaltes to select * from reference('t') which is mentioned here
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/native-apps/requesting-refs#label-native-apps-supported-privs-references
note that corresponding part of manifest.yml which makes the frontend clickable to set this reference is following
references:
  - t:
      label: "t table" 
      description: "Select table"
      privileges:
        - SELECT
      object_type: Table 
      multi_valued: false 
      register_callback: app_instance_schema.update_reference 

note that in manifest "t" has to correspond to your reference it cannot be named like my_awesome_t_table if you're using your 't' in the procedures.
Note also that the procedure i wrote doesnt make sense in this example because the only reference i make is to 't' so parameterization does not make sense ( will be able to call it with argument 't' only, but if i add more table this will be useful )
[edit3] there is an even better way via granting privileges to applications: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege-application
this way you can skip the reference syntax

Unrelated to the question, and I'm assuming this is just for exploring/learning, but just in case, that procedure is very unsafe to expose to an application where an end user can provide whatever lands in the t variable as it's open to a sql injection attack.

yes the procedure is for testing purposes - i was trying to make the snowflake app have the privileges, sorry for a bad question, but i was unable to find it on the internet so maybe it will help somebody now that i figured it out. However the reference syntax guards from the sql injection

Gotcha. I haven't messed with the refernece() syntax. My bad. Perhaps Snowflake protects us from shooting ourselves in the foot. If you could, I think it would be helpful to move your edit into an actual answer for this question. It's totally ok for folks to answer their own questions on here, and like you said, it may help someone in the future.
